# Zooming in WKInterfaceMap with a slider (WKInterfaceSlider)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, zooming, watchkit

I have a slider on my map and I am trying to zoom in via the slider. Below is the code that I am using and when the + or - is hit the map just shows blue(water)

```
  - (IBAction)sliderAction:(float)value {
        RestaurantObject *restaurant = [nearbyMapArray objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D mapLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([restaurant.latitude doubleValue]*value, [restaurant.longitude doubleValue]*value);
        MKCoordinateSpan coordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1, 1);
        [self.map setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapLocation, coordinateSpan))];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably passing values of latitude and longitude in wrong place.
try this , should work

```
- (IBAction)sliderAction:(UISlider*)slider
{
    CGFloat value = slider.value; // slider.maximumValue - slider.value // if you want reverse effect
    CGFloat sliderMax = slider.maximumValue;
    CGFloat zoom = value / sliderMax;
    RestaurantObject *restaurant = [nearbyMapArray objectAtIndex:0];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D mapLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([restaurant.latitude doubleValue], [restaurant.longitude doubleValue]);
    MKCoordinateSpan coordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1*zoom, 1*zoom);
    [self.map setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapLocation, coordinateSpan))];
}
```